# Angular 2 CORS запрос не проходит

Tags: angular2

Делаю авторизацию через jwt.

Back-end: Spring, настроены CORS, фильтры и т.д.

Front-end: Angular 2 rc5, пытаюсь отправить POST запрос с данными для авторизации, первый запрос OPTIONS проходит успешно(сервер отвечает Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <клиент>), потом успешно проходит и сам POST запрос, НО почему то ангуляр ругается:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load <сервер>/api/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<клиент>' is therefore not allowed access.`

и соответственно в ангуляре я никак не могу использовать ответ от запроса.

---

вот как эти два запроса(OPTIONS и POST) видит инспектор хрома

[image: img1]

---

как видно всё с ними в порядке, но ошибка всё равно есть, кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким или знает в чем проблема?

[image: img2]

Comment: 8080 - это сервер, 4200 - это клиент и запрос ПРОХОДИТ, т.е. если посмотреть в инспекторе, то все мне нужные данные запрос вернул, а ангуляр их игнорирует и кидает ошибку

Answer (score 1):

У Angular в конфиге стоит `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;` ? 
Можете добавить сам конфиг Angular, и Spring где разрешены CORS?

Comment: с withCredentials тоже пробова, разрешен в /api/**. Проблема была на сервере(или нет:)), переписал авторизацию через обычный контроллер, а не через AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter, всё равно непонятно почему не работало

Answer (score 0):

В заголовке Access-Control-Allow-Methods через запятую должны быть перечислены все методы, для которых разрешается выполнение с адреса, указанного в Access-Control-Allow-Origin. То есть "POST,OPTIONS". В заголовке Access-Control-Allow-Headers через запятую должны быть перечислены все заголовки (не относящиеся к группе Access-Control-Allow-*), для которых будет выполняться проверка Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Судя по всему у вас метод OPTIONS отправляется без специфических заголовков и по этому проходит нормально, а в POST какие-то заголовки вы устанавливаете. Вот они, видимо, и блокируют запрос.